# Does @PreUpdate always run when @PrePersist runs?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have an Entity like below:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

  @Id
  private String orderId;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
  private Date created;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
  private Date updated;
  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    this.created = new Date();
    this.updated = this.created;
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    this.updated = new Date();
  }
}
```

I have to find all the orders that have created or updated date within a particular date range. For that I have below method defined in my repository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, String>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
 public Page<Order> findByCreatedBetweenOrUpdatedBetween(Date startCreatedDate,
      Date endCreatedDate, Date startUpdatedDate, Date endUptedDate, Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

My question is, can I just check for `Updated_date` for this instead of both created and updated date like below?

```
public Page<Order> findByUpdatedBetween(Date startUpdatedDate, Date endUptedDate, Pageable pageRequest);
```

What I observed is `updated_date` is updated at the time a row in inserted with the same value as `created_date`. Is there a chance I would miss any of the records if I just check updated_date for the date range provided.

Comment: Aren't you setting the updated date in `@PrePersist` `this.updated = this.created;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `@PreUpdate` callback method does not always run when `@PrePersist` callback method is executed. `@PrePersist` is executed before persist operation (direct or cascaded) and `@PreUpdate` before database update.

In JPA 2.1 specification (3.5.3 Semantics of the Life Cycle Callback Methods for Entities) this is told with following words:

> The PrePersist and PreRemove callback  methods are invoked for a given
>   entity before the respective EntityManager persist and remove
>   operations for that entity are executed.
>   ...
>   The PreUpdate and
>   PostUpdate callbacks occur before and after the database update
>   operations to entity data respectively.