# How to override JPA @PrePersist behaviour for a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa

I have the following JPA entity:

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "My_Table")
public class MyTableEntity {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "creationdatetime")
    private LocalDateTime creationDateTime;

    @Column(name = "updatedatetime")
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
    this.creationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.updateDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

I have a unit test where I am doing this:

```java
   LocalDateTime creationDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(100);
   MyTableEntity entity = 
   MyTableEntity.builder()
           .id(1)
           .build();
   entity.setCreationDateTime(creationDate)
   entity.setUpdateDateTime(creationDate)
```

However, later on in my unit test, the value I'm setting for creation date time and update date time  is magically getting changed as per what is defined in the `@PrePersist` method in my JPA entity.

Solely for the purpose of unit testing, how can I stop `@PrePersist` from overriding values I'm explicitly setting during the unit test?

(If it, helps I am using Mockito.)

Comment: You can't. You'll need to enter the data in the DB in a different way (e.g. preload some data), or otherwise design around this.

Comment: It seems like pre-persist is happening even before I got to save the jpa entity, is that expected?

Comment: No...it needs to be saved/persisted for the [callback to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439080/2541560). If you're trying to "hack around" this, you're wasting your time in a huge way. Either preload the data in the DB, or depending on what you're actually trying to test, design the test in a different way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is adding check in the `MyTableEntity#onCreate` method:

```java
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    if(creationDateTime == null){
        this.creationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    if(updateDateTime == null){
        this.updateDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Then the values you set in the unit test won't be rewritten.

Another option is passing `onCreate` code from outside.

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "My_Table")
public class MyTableEntity {

    ///  ... 

    @Transient
    private Consumer<MyTableEntity> onCreateConsumer = mte -> {
        mte.creationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        mte.updateDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    };

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        onCreateConsumer.accept(this);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to set onCreateConsumer in the unit test:

```java
MyTableEntity.builder()
   .id(1)
   .onCreateConsumer(e -> {}) // do nothing
   .build();
```

Comment: thanks these ideas helped me a lot. The first one did the trick actually. Nice and simple.